# How to understand this locking-machanizion in Mysql [update A=x where A=y]

Tags: mysql

Mysql 8.0.23

innodb

REPEATABLE-READ

1  create table and insert

```
   CREATE TABLE test     
      (      
       id INT(11) auto_increment,    
       num int,      
       primary key (id) ,
       index(num)
     );
   insert into test values(null,1000);
   insert into test values(null,2000);
```

2  Session 1 begin Transaction，not commit

```
    mysql> select * from test;
+----+------+
| id | num  |
+----+------+
|  1 | 1000 |
|  2 | 2000 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> update test set num=9000 where num =1000;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

3 Session 2 just execute sql

```
  update test set num=-1000 where num=2000;    // blocked!!
  update test set num=0 where num=2000;    // blocked!!
  update test set num=1000 where num=2000; // blocked!!
  update test set num=1999 where num=2000  // blocked!!
  update test set num=2000 where num=2000  // SUCCESS!!
  update test set num=4000 where num=2000  // SUCCESS!!
```

So the lock in this situation is **(-∞，2000)**

How Can I understand this locking-machanizion?

why ths gap locks is not [1000,2000)

I know the update sql in mysql innodb will be delete + insert

but I can not understand why the table will lock in (-∞，2000)

---

And then :

```
 Seesion1  update test set num=9000 where num=2000;// not commit
 Seesion2  update test set num=0 where num=1000;//  Success
           update test set num=1000 where num=1000;//  Success
           update test set num=1001 where num=1000;//  BLock
           update test set num=9000 where num=1000;//  BLock
```

So the lock in this situation is **(1000，+∞)**

I am so  confused ！